# Why did my mesh disappear after using remesh modifier?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry

I was trying to clean up the geometry of letter "N" after I converted it from text to mesh.

But the mesh of letter *"N"* disappears after I apply the *Remesh modifier*.
Making *Octree Depth* higher did not make the mesh reappear.

**Q:** Does anyone know the best way to clean up the geometry of a mesh?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this modifier object has to be a 3D. Your N is only 2D.

To clean up go to edit mode, select all vertices and press **X > Limited Dissolve**.

[image]

Or select all vertices and press **F** (Make Face)

For more info https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html

Answer (score 1):

The [*Remesh Modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html) requires a mesh with surface curvature, which a completely planar model doesn't have. You could add a *Solidify Modifier* before the *Remesh Modifier* to make it work properly. This is also suggested by the manual:

> The input mesh should have some thickness to it. If the input is completely flat, add a Solidify Modifier above the Remesh one.

If you're only interested in having planar geometry, you could delete the extruded part of the letter after applying the modifiers.